# Matlab counting elements in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hey guys I just have a quick question regarding counting elements in an array.
the array is something like this

```
B = [1 0 1 0 0 -1; 1 1 1 0 -1 -1; 0 1 -1 0 0 1]
```

From this array i want to create an array structure, called column counts and another row counts. I really do want to crate an array structure, even if it is a less efficient process.

basically i want to go through the array and total for each column, row the total amount of times these values occur. For instance for the first row, i want the following output.

```
Row Counts
-1 0 1

 1 3 2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [hist](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function to do this.

```
fprintf('Row counts\n');
disp([-1 0 1])
fprintf('\n')
for row = 1:3
    disp(hist(m(i,:),3));
end
```

yields

```
Row counts
-1      0      1

 1      3      2
 2      1      3
 1      3      2
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you want to count the occurrences of an element in a Matlab array you can do something like:

```
% Find value 3 in array A
A =[ 1 4 5 3 3 1 2 4 2 3 ];
count = sum( A == 3 )
```

When comparing `A==3` Matlab will fill an array with 0 and 1, meaning the second one that the element in the given position in `A` has the element you were looking for. So you can count the occurrences by accumulating the values in the array `A==3`

Edit: you can access the different dimensions like that:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4  ];  % 3rows x 4columns matrix
count1 = sum( A(:,1) == 2 );         % count occurrences in the first column
count2 = sum( A(:,3) == 2 );         % '                      ' third column
count3 = sum( A(2,:) == 2 );         % '                      ' second row
```

You always access given rows or columns like that.

Comment: Secondly, if i want to count the occurances in the other dimension, as in for the col counts. how do you do that/

Comment: Secondly, if i want to count the occurances in the other dimension, as in for the col counts. how do you do that?

Comment: is there a way to access all the rows in one statement?

Comment: As far as I know you can access in a single statement all the rows in a given column (A(:,i)) or all the columns in a given row (A(i,:)), but not what you purpose. You'd better post a new question and I'll be glad to look at the answers!